# For Loop writing records to a file prints only last item

Tags: javascript, json, file, for-loop, console.log

I'm trying to write forloop to a json file and it only prints last item in an array

```
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./input_data.json');
    let jsondata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    let result='';
    let key='';
    let data = {
       items: []
    } 
    myrecords=[];
      for(let i = 0; i < jsondata.records.length; i++) {
        let obj = jsondata.records[i];
        result = obj.Id
        items = jsondata.records[i].data
        data.items = [items];
        data.key=result
        myrecords.push(data)
      }
   var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.json', {flags : 'w'});
   var log_stdout = process.stdout;
   console.log = function(d) {
    log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
    log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
   };
   console.log(JSON.stringify(myrecords, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `data` object again and again in the loop and the reference you are pushing into `myrecords`.
Hence, all the elements in `myrecords` references the same `data` object. When modifying the object in the loop, it affects all the previously added items.

You should create a new `data` object in each iteration of the loop.

Try the following:

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./input_data.json');
let jsondata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
let myrecords = [];

for (let i = 0; i < jsondata.records.length; i++) {
  let obj = jsondata.records[i];
  let result = obj.Id;
  let items = jsondata.records[i].data;
  let data = {
    items: [items],
    key: result
  };
  myrecords.push(data);
}

var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.json', { flags: 'w' });
var log_stdout = process.stdout;
console.log = function (d) {
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(myrecords, null, 2));
```

Comment: @Mamun-Thanks for the explanation. It works fine as expected.